# Connected Hausdorff spaces with large collection of disjoint open sets

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Is there for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$ a connected Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ with $|X| = \kappa$ and a collection ${\cal D}$ of mutually disjoint open sets with $|{\cal D}| = \kappa$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/358533/129074) of Wlod AA, such a space always exists for $\kappa$ infinite (it is clear that it cannot exist for $2\leq\kappa<\omega$).

Let $I$ be a countable Hausdorff connected space (see [A connected countable Hausdorff space](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9.pdf), R. H. Bing, 1952), and $x$ any point in $I$. Then the quotient $(I\times\kappa)/(\lbrace x\rbrace\times\kappa)$ is such a space ($\kappa$ is considered as a discrete space), with $\mathcal D$ the collection of open sets $(I\setminus\lbrace x\rbrace)\times\lbrace\alpha\rbrace$ for $\alpha<\kappa$.

Answer (score 2):

For every $\ \kappa\ge|\Bbb R| \ $ the cone
$\ X=\text{cone(D)}\ $ over the discrete space $\ D\ $ of cardinality $\ \kappa\ $ is an example.

The required open sets are the cone lines minus the vertex.

*When it comes to lower cardinalities then I'd look into the Urysohn countable connected Hausdorff space.*

In particular, let's apply the Bing's example of Hausdorff connected countable space, $\ B\ $ (see https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9.pdf)

Any infinite family of pairwise disjoint euclidean-open subsets of $\ \Bbb Q\times\{0\}\ $ are open also in $\ B.\ $

Thus the OP's problem is solved for all cardinalities but the weird ones, between $\ |\Bbb Q|\ $ and $\ |\Bbb R|,\ $ that exist only when we don't accept the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Can't you just take the “$B$-cone” over the discrete space $\kappa$ then? Just taking the quotient of $\kappa\times B$ by $\kappa\times\lbrace x\rbrace$ for $x$ any point in $B$.

Comment: @PierrePC, that's exactly what I've written in my answer above (for  ≥|ℝ|).

Comment: I know, I got all the ingredients from your answer. But this would work for any cardinality if you replaced $[0,1]$ by the $B$ you describe in the construction of the cone. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Pierre, yes, what you did is great!!! I should read with greater attention and a positive attitude. Please, post your solution since it's elegant and complete! #### (I didn't pay any attention to your B like Bing; to me, "B" is for Banach :) ).

Comment: No worries. :) But don't you want to just edit your answer? Everything is already here really. You can cite the comment if you're worried about copyright issues. ;)

Comment: Please, It is your job, your answer! BTW, I see that @bof got a similar idea.